# Error : Unable to create FirestoreClient The requested client requires the gRPC extension

Tags: php, linux, laravel, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I am using a library to integrate Firebase SDK with laravel and when i try to create a FirestoreClient i am getting this error :

" Unable to create a FirestoreClient: The requested client requires the gRPC extension "

I am using ubuntu 18.04.3 and laravel 6.

I have already tried following this tutorial :

https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

and it seems that i have installed the extension successfully as i have added the extension in the php.ini file as well and the composer.json file is showing the grpc in the packages like this:

"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "google/cloud": "^0.116.0",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.10",
        "google/protobuf": "^v3.3.0",
        "grpc/grpc": "^v1.1.0",
        "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },

But still getting the error when i try to create a client from the controller.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the php.ini for apache2 as this is the webserver i am using

Comment: Thanks for the compliment but of course i have done this, i have restart the apache server after adding that extension.

Comment: Oh sorry i got that wrong, let me check a quick please.

Comment: i have checked using var_dump(extension_loaded('grpc')); and its showing bool(false) also  i couldn't find the grpc in phpinfo() as well. but i have already added the extension you can see in this screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/xbiO3KA

Comment: There should be an error in the apache error log then, if the extension failed to load. Have you checked that?

Comment: Have you tried installing and enabling another extension? Another thing you can try is to run php from the command line: `php -d extension=grpc.so test.php`. If even that fails, that means your grpc.so wasn't installed into the proper directory. Run `php -i | grep extension_dir` you should see where the extension are supposed to be install to